# How to delete specify items of List using lambda in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Have such situation. 
There are two lists: `list1` as `List(of Integer)` and `list2` as `List(of Integer)`.

I need to remove all items of list1 that are same as items of list2.

For example:

```
list1 = 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 10
list2 = 3, 6
```

After removing list2 from list1 : `list1 = 0, 1, 2, 10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list1.RemoveAll(Function(i) list2.Contains(i))
```

or just with the delegate

```
list1.RemoveAll(AddressOf list2.Contains)
```

As noted from Meta-Knight, if `list2` is just a lookup list which cannot contain duplicates anyway you better use a `HashSet(Of Int32)` instead. It has a `O(1)` lookup complexity which is independend of it's size with the downside of requiring more memory if you also need `list2`.

You can create one easily:

```
Dim setOfNums = new HashSet(Of Int32)(list2)
list1.RemoveAll(AddressOf setOfNums.Contains)
```

Comment: +1. If you have lists with many items, list2 should be a HashSet for quicker lookup. The rest of the code would remain the same.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Thanks, edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: Does not work if `list1` can contain duplicates as in `{0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1}`. The result would be `{0, 1, 2}` instead of `{0, 1, 2, 1}`. Needs also to create a new collection and assign that to the old.